# What does the "Commands" scope do?

Tags: unity, scopes

In Ubuntu 13.10 there is a "Commands" scope. I was wondering what this one filters for and where I can read about what it does.

Answer (score 2):

The commands scope provides the backend for the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> dash screen used to run arbitrary commands.  It also maintains the history list for previous commands that have been run through this interface.

It is not invoked by the standard dash view shown when you press <kbd>Super</kbd>/<kbd>Win</kbd>.

Comment: How did you learn this?

Comment: I'm a member of the Unity API team (the group at Canonical responsible for the scopes infrastructure).